# Is there something like Testflight for Windows Phone 8?

Tags: testing, windows-8, windows-phone-8, testflight

How can I get my developed app(Windows Phone 8) to a testing-device without installing it directly with Visual studio? 
We have some customers who are hundred miles away. How can they get their app before publishing it in the store(They want to test it before)?
For IOS we use Testflight. **Is there something like Testflight for Windows Phone 8?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can publish it to the store as a beta application - you will need the account ids of those that you want to be able to install/test it, but that should allow them to be able to install it, whilst other people cannot, and without having to go through the full QA process normally associated with submitting an app.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is called [Beta Distribution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj215598%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) on Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

If they have a developer account and developer tools installed, they can use the Windows Phone Developer Registration tool and Application Deployment tool to deploy.  See the Windows Phone Developer Center article for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769508(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think HockeyApp supports Windows Phone 8:
http://hockeyapp.net/blog/2014/01/08/hockeyapp-for-windows.html